# Is there any way to pass selected row data from Power BI report to Asp.net application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, powerbi

In my requirement, I have **power BI** report in which I will select some of rows.
From here I need to send the **selected rows** (Id) information to **ASP.Net application**.

Please suggest me how to proceed on it.

Thanking you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is no provision to share the information to external application.

Having said that, the approach I can think of is have a PowerApp Visual linked to the report which will display the selected Row (or develop the complete POWERAPP UI to have the necessary information). Sharing the approach at a very high level.

When you embed a PowerBI visual in the Power BI Report. The data will be automatically shared with the PowerApp. The filtering applied at the report page will also reflect on the data appearing the in the PowerApp visual. So if you select one row, only that row will appear in the Power App Visual

**Sample**
[image]

Once the necessary report data has been shared to PowerApp, on a button click code, you could trigger HTTP request / trigger a flow which we will capture necessary data & pass/sharing the data to external system.

More information on the PowerApp integ with PowerBI :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/powerapps-custom-visual

Answer (score 0):

You can handle [`dataSelected`](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Handling-Events) event, in which you will get a list of data points selected in the visual. There is [an official demo](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/dataselection.html), which unfortunately doesn't work last few times when I checked, [but the code can be seen directly](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/app/dataselection.js). Then from this event, you can pass the selection the way you want.

Here is how the demo looked like when it works:

[image]

Comment: This post fit to my requirement, Thank you so much..

Comment: how to handle button click event of power bi report from MVC application. thanking you in advance